# Want to take value from input procedure to output procedure using push and pop

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

I m using MASM compilor and DOSBOX. I am taking 2 hex number in **input proc** which works fine and now i want to print those numbers in **output proc** How can i do this using push and pop such that push numbers in input proc and pop them in **output proc**. kindly let me know how can i use push and pop

```
   .model small
   .stack 100h

    .data
    B DB 30 DUP(?)
   .code
  MAIN PROC
  mov si, offset B

    CALL Take_Hex_Input
     mov DL,AL

    CALL PRINT_HEX_Output  
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
   Main endp
   TAKE_HEX_INPUT PROC NEAR
   xor bx,bx
     mov cl, 2
     mov ah, 1
     int 21h
     cmp al,'f'
     JG terminate
     cmp al,39h
     JG letter
     cmp al,'a'
     JL newcheck
     cmp al,30h
     JL letter

 AND al,0Fh
    JMP shift
   letter:
  sub al,37h
   shift:
   shl bl,cl
   OR bl,al

   int 21h
   Ret
   newcheck:
     cmp al,'0'
     JL terminate
     cmp al,30h
     JL letter
     cmp al,'9'
     JG terminate
     cmp al,30h
     JG letter
    Terminate:
    mov ah,4ch
     int 21h
   TAKE_HEX_INPUT endp

   PRINT_HEX_Output PROC NEAR



  mov ah,2
  MOV dl,al
  int 21h


 PRINT_HEX_Output endp


 End Main
```

Comment: It's not clear what is input of `output` procedure, and what is desired output on screen. Two hex numbers? You mean two digits? like `00-FF` numbers? If it's like that, then once converted from string to value, it will fit into 8 bits (single 8b register), is that input of `output`? And you want to print it in which format? Decimal (`0-255`), or again hexa (`00-FF`)? And `push/pop` between different `call` will be very tricky, as `call/ret` itself works with stack. So if you insist on using stack memory, you have to allocate some spare before `call input` and use that one in both procedures.

Comment: I don't have sufficient rep to see [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095177/want-to-input-2-hex-numbers-and-print-them-assmbly-language?noredirect=1#comment69396939_41095177) but IIRC it was **very** similar to this one from a different user. Coincidence?

Comment: Try to improve your question, add examples, what you tried, what exactly is your problem. If I understand you correctly, you take two letters input from user, like "AB", and that should produce later on output again "AB". Do you want to validate the input (if it is two hexa digits)? Are you *required* to convert it to numeric value internally? If not, you can just read it as string input and output it back, without any calculations. If yes, calculate the value, it will fit into 8b register (`00-FF` is exactly full range of 8 bit value). Give that value to `output` and convert it to two chars.

Comment: Well, take a look at ASCII table, to understand what is input value for int 21h, 2. When you load `dl` with `0x30`, it will display `"0"`. To display two digits, you have to call that service twice, with two ASCII codes in `dl`. Calling it with `dl=0x34` and then `dl=0x41` will produce on screen "4A". So if you have at start of `output` value `0x4A` in register, you have to split it into two digits (split it to 4:4 bits by shifting/anding), then convert the two 4b `0-F` values into `0x30-0x39` for 0-9, and `0x41-0x46` for 10-15.  ... overall try to get grasp of what is "bit" and why 4b is 0-F.

Comment: @julie We already have a lot of question about printing numbers. Including an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3273/converting-decimal-strings-to-integers/26175/ms-dos-tasm-masm-function-to-print-a-16-bit-number-in-binary-quaternary-octal#t=201612121404363837997) in Documentation. It is generalised for every base power of two but you can simplify it to work only with hex (you can also remove the handling of the leading zeros). That's still a good exercise and equivalent of writing a method from scratch. Pick the one you find easier.

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hexadecimal  check especially converting to/from binary chapter. Then realize the CPU itself is storing numeric values in bits, so de facto in "binary". And finally run your code in debugger, stepping over single instructions, watching values in registers, to figure out what is your true result of `input` and what `output` does with it.

Comment: Which one? Original 8086 has many 16b registers, some of them also accessible as two 8b partial registers (pair `ah:al` is together `ax`). If you use 16b register, you may put two numbers into upper/lower 8bits. If it was `ax`, you can use `ah`/`al` directly. If you want to put those numbers into single 8b register, you have to decide how they will be encoded into 8 bits. `0-9` is ten values, that requires 4 bits (4 bits can store 16 values). Split single 8b register into 4:4 bit parts, and set each part with one number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation to manipulate bits.

Comment: Or you can store those values as `0-99` (7 bits total, 7 bits allow for 128 different values) and then use division by 10 to split them apart. Or you can create even more complex encoding like interleave the bits per one, etc... As I wrote earlier, you need to grasp what is "bit" and how computer is storing information. Then learn basic instructions to manipulate that. Learn which registers are available (fast playground for CPU), how to access/modify memory content (slow-but-large playground for CPU). Then any task convert into calculation from input numbers into output numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a value in stack in **input proc** and get it from stack inside **output proc** you can use register `BP` to access the stack. This is what next example does :

- It reserves two bytes in stack (`push ax`) to store the two keys pressed.
- It calls `input` to read two keys and store them in the reserved two bytes in stack using `BP`.
- It calls `output` where `BP` is used to access the stack and extract the keys.
- The two bytes in stack are released (`pop ax`).

Now the example code :

```
 .model small
 .stack 100h

  .code
 main proc   
 push ax             ;◄■■ RESERVE MEMORY IN STACK FOR TWO KEYS.
 call input
 call output
 pop  ax             ;◄■■ RELEASE MEMORY FROM STACK.

 terminate:
 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h

  main endp


INPUT PROC NEAR
;▼ CAPTURE TWO KEYS.
   mov  ah, 1         ;◄■■ READ FIRST KEY.
   int  21h
   mov  bl, al        ;◄■■ SAVE FIRST KEY IN BL.
   mov  ah, 1         ;◄■■ READ SECOND KEY.
   int  21h
   mov  bh, al        ;◄■■ SAVE SECOND KEY IN BH.
;▼ STORE BOTH KEYS IN STACK.   
   mov  bp, sp        ;◄■■ ACCESS THE STACK.
   mov  [bp+2], bx    ;◄■■ SAVE KEYS IN STACK.
   ret
input endp


OUTPUT PROC NEAR
   mov bp, sp         ;◄■■ ACCESS THE STACK.
   mov cx, [bp+2]     ;◄■■ GET BOTH KEYS FROM STACK.
;▼ OUTPUT FIRST KEY.   
   mov dl,cl          ;◄■■ FIRST KEY FROM CL.
   mov ah,2
   int 21h
;▼ OUTPUT SECOND KEY.   
   mov dl,ch          ;◄■■ SECOND KEY FROM CH.
   mov ah,2
   int 21h
   ret
output endp

   end main
```

Comment: Oh thanx @jose using input and outproc i want to take hex numbers in input proc using input and then print them using output proc. and validation is also there to chekc if any of the numbers is not hex then terminate the program

Comment: @joze how much time will it take to complete this code ? :)

Comment: @joze can u correct me within 2 hours? i hav to submit an assignmnt  so please pleas correct it

Comment: @joze m waiting for u m depending on u come back soon please correc my code

Comment: @joze it says that your vote is recorded but wil not be shown in public